# How do you read txt files and display the results in a grid headers in Visual Basic 2010 express?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

This sounds so simple but I still can't find the answer to it after googling for a while. I have DataGridView on a form and it's called DataGridView1. I have two txt files (with single columns in each) data and I want to be able to display them as Row & Column headings (not as cell contents). For example, the two txt files are

1. C:\temp\sObj.txt
2. C:\temp\sQue.txt

Now:
 sObj.txt contains data a, b & c in a single column &
     sQue.txt contains data d, e & f in a single column.
Now what I want looks like:

```
a  b  c
d
e
f
```

Please help, I'm a beginner in programming & need this be done urgently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already said in the comment section, you need a `StreamReader` to read the lines of your textfile.
First of all you have to import the `System.IO`-namespace:

```
Import System.IO
```

So declare your `StreamReader` with the filepath to your textfile and read each line in it.

Then you have to add the text of your StreamReader as a Column to your DataGridView.
The first parameter is the ColumnName, the second is the ColumnHeading:

```
Using reader As New StreamReader(@"YOURFILEPATHHERE")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(reader.ReadLine(),reader.ReadLine())
End Using
```

So now you have added your columns. Adding your Rows is easier:

Simply read the lines and add your Rows with your `String` (linetext) as the parameter:

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(reader.ReadLine())
```

It's pretty easy and you could have done that with minimal research.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was useful to me to build my own solution , I would like to share it with others;

```
Private Sub LoadColumnsInDGV(FileName As String)
    Try
        Dim sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(FileName)
        Dim TxtNewLine As String
        Dim IsFlagFound As Boolean = True
        Dim NewColName As String
        Dim SplitLine() As String

        Do While sr.Peek() > -1
            TxtNewLine = Trim(sr.ReadLine()) & vbNewLine
            SplitLine = Split(TxtNewLine, vbTab)
            If IsFlagFound Then
                For i = 0 To SplitLine.Length - 1
                    NewColName = Trim(SplitLine(i))
                    NewColName = NewColName.Replace(vbNewLine, Nothing)
                    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(NewColName, NewColName)
                Next
                IsFlagFound = False
            Else
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
            End If
        Loop
        sr.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error on Sub LoadColumnsInDGV " & vbCrLf & ex.Source & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```