# Import CSV file to database using VB

Tags: vb.net

I need to import the information from a CSV txt file to a database using the DataGridView in my form.  The application should allow the user to open a .txt file and then update the DataGridView table in my form.  I am able to get the file, but am unable to update the grid using the file.  I can update textboxes, but cannot figure out how to update the grid.  Can anyone help me out with this?

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
Private fileToOpen As String                'the file to be opened and read
Private responseFileDialog As DialogResult  'response from OpenFileDialog
Private myStreamReader As StreamReader      'the reader object to get contents of file
Private myStreamWriter As StreamWriter      'the writer object to save contents of textbox
Private myTextFieldParser As TextFieldParser    ' To parse text to searched.
Dim myDataAdapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim myString() As String
Dim myRow As DataRow



Private Sub PeopleBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PeopleBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.PeopleBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.MyContactsDataSet)

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MyContactsDataSet.People' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.PeopleTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MyContactsDataSet.People)

End Sub

Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim fileContentString As String         'contents of the file
    Dim update As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter)
    'Dim myRow As DataRow

    'set the properties of the OpenFileDialog object
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select File to View..."
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"


    'responseFileDialog contains holds the response of the user (which button they selected)
    responseFileDialog = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

    'check to see if the user select OKAY, if not they selected CANCEL so don't open anything
    If (responseFileDialog <> System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel) Then
        'make sure there isn't a file already open, if there is then close it
        If (myStreamReader IsNot Nothing) Then
            myStreamReader.Close()
            'TextBoxFileOutput.Clear()
        End If

        'open the file and read its text and display in the textbox
        fileToOpen = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        myStreamReader = New StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)

        initTextFieldParser()

        'loop through the file reading its text and adding it to the textbox on the form
        Do Until myStreamReader.Peek = -1
            fileContentString = myStreamReader.ReadLine()

            'Try
            '    myTextFieldParser = New TextFieldParser(fileToOpen)
            '    myTextFieldParser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited
            '    myTextFieldParser.SetDelimiters(",")
            'Catch ex As Exception
            '    MessageBox.Show("Cannot Open File to Be Read!")
            'End Try


            myTextFieldParser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited

            myString = TextFieldParser.NewLine()

            myRow.Item("FirstName") = myString(1)

            MyContactsDataSet.Tables("People").Rows.Add(myRow)
            PeopleTableAdapter.Update(MyContactsDataSet)
            'TextBoxFileOutput.AppendText(fileContentString)
            'TextBoxFileOutput.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
        Loop

        'close the StreamReader now that we are done with it
        myStreamReader.Close()
        'SaveToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub initTextFieldParser()
    'Close myTextFieldParser in case the user is surfing through the records and then
    'decides to search for a particular last name --> Basically      start searching from beginning of the file
    If (myTextFieldParser IsNot Nothing) Then
        myTextFieldParser.Close()
    End If

    Try
        myTextFieldParser = New TextFieldParser(fileToOpen)
        myTextFieldParser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited
        myTextFieldParser.SetDelimiters(",")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot Open File to Be Read!")
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that you've tried out so far and is not working?

Comment: I just scrapped it and am starting over.  I will put what I have up shortly.  Thank you!!

Comment: MANY missing details. If the user is supposed to be able to edit/view the data *before* saving, parse the data to an empty (typed) DataTable and bind it to the DGV.  Use something like TextFieldParser, OleDB or CSVHelper to parse the csv text file.  Zillions of questions here on how to,

Comment: I added my code so far.  I need to parse the data from the CSV file to the DataGridView.  I know how to parse it to a text box, but I do not know how to parse it to the Grid.

Comment: I have since updated my code the section of code that is not working is:       myString = TextFieldParser.NewLine()

Comment: [How to read from a CSV into a typed Datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28856448/1070452)

Answer (score 0):

updating gridview with your file content

**Import System.IO** as we gonna need StreamReader

```
Using reader As New StreamReader("filepath")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("col1",reader.ReadToEnd())
End Using
```

check this [out!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859657/how-do-you-read-txt-files-and-display-the-results-in-a-grid-headers-in-visual-ba)